# Installing Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0.0beta on AWS EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

Installing Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0beta1 on the default Amazon EC2 Linux install (Amazon Linux AMI 2012.09.1) goes smoothly.
But openssl gets in the way (eg http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html) and weird either prevent openssl from getting installed or causing the RubyGem package manager from installing rails.

How can I work around these problems?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Log into your brand new instance:

```
[19:59:22] paul:~ $ ssh -i ~/.ssh/server.pem ec2-user@your.ip

   __|  __|_  )
   _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
  ___|\___|___|

  https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2012.09-release-notes/
```

and impersonate the root:

```
$ sudo su -
```

You are logged in as root from here. Apply the server updates:

```
[root@ip-xx ~]# yum update
...
Complete!
[root@ip-xx ~]# yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
...
Install      72 Package(s)
...
Complete!
```

Now, this is where it differs from the standard solution. Install RVM but without a distribution of ruby:

```
[root@ip-xx ~]# \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    135      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   183
100 11861  100 11861    0     0   7180      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 64113
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124  100   124    0     0    161      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   185
100 1615k  100 1615k    0     0   258k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--  401k

Installing RVM to /usr/local/rvm/
    Creating group 'rvm'

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.io/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm/
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues read output of 'rvm requirements' and/or 'rvm notes'

Installation of RVM in /usr/local/rvm/ is almost complete:

  * First you need to add all users that will be using rvm to 'rvm' group,
    and logout - login again, anyone using rvm will be operating with `umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx`.

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

# root,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and
#   more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne
```

Let's check that no ruby version is installed:

```
[root@ip-xx ~]# rvm list

rvm rubies


# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.
```

Now, openssl is already installed on the system but is incompatible with setup:

```
[root@ip-xx ~]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.0k-fips 5 Feb 2013

[root@ip-xx ~]# openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
```

Attempting to install ruby2 with this version will result in the following error:

```
[root@ip-xx ~]# rvm install 2.0.0 -- --with-openssl-dir=/etc/pki/tls
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /usr/local/rvm/archives
######################################################################## 100.0%
Extracting yaml to /usr/local/rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4
Prepare yaml in /usr/local/rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Configuring yaml in /usr/local/rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /usr/local/rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /usr/local/rvm/usr
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
######################################################################## 100.0%
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p0 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #configuring
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #compiling
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #installing 
Retrieving rubygems-2.0.3
######################################################################## 100.0%
Extracting rubygems-2.0.3 ...
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-2.0.3 for ruby-2.0.0-p0 ...
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.3/setup.rb', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
Saving wrappers to '/usr/local/rvm/bin'.
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/gem'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/erb'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ri'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/rdoc'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/testrb'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/rake'? y
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #importing default gemsets, this may take time ...
Install of ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #complete
```

Although you'll get ruby2, the "Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully" - notice the warning: "Error running 'env GEM_PATH=..."

Instead, we'll get RVM install a copy of openssl for us (see https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/). The zlib-devel package is required:

```
[root@ip-xx ~]# yum install zlib-devel
...
Installed:
  zlib-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.5-7.11.amzn1                                                                                  

Complete!
[root@ip-xx ~]# rvm pkg install openssl
Fetching openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz to /usr/local/rvm/archives
Extracting openssl to /usr/local/rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c
Configuring openssl in /usr/local/rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Compiling openssl in /usr/local/rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Installing openssl to /usr/local/rvm/usr

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Updating openssl certificates
```

We can now install ruby2:

```
[root@ip-xx ~]# rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr
Removing /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0...
Removing /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0...
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p0 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #configuring
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #compiling
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-2.0.3 for ruby-2.0.0-p0 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
Saving wrappers to '/usr/local/rvm/bin'.
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/gem'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/erb'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ri'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/rdoc'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/testrb'? y
cp: overwrite `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/rake'? y
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #importing default gemsets, this may take time ...
Install of ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #complete 
Making gemset ruby-2.0.0-p0 pristine.
Making gemset ruby-2.0.0-p0@global pristine.

[root@ip-xx ~]# ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]
```

And rails4:

```
[root@ip-xx ~]# gem install rails -v 4.0.0beta1
...
28 gems installed
[root@ip-xx ~]# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.0.beta1)
actionpack (4.0.0.beta1)
activemodel (4.0.0.beta1)
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (0.0.3)
activesupport (4.0.0.beta1)
arel (4.0.0.beta2)
atomic (1.0.1)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.1.4)
bundler (1.3.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
mail (2.5.3)
mime-types (1.21)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.7.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0.beta1)
railties (4.0.0.beta1)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0, 3.12.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
sprockets (2.9.0)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0.rc3)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.17.0)
thread_safe (0.1.0)
tilt (1.3.6)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
```

That's all folks!

Comment: Other things to consider. Nokogiri gem fails to install if libxml2-devel and libxslt-devel are not installed so:  *# yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel*

Comment: And current release of Passenger doesn't work with ruby2 so you'll need to install a pre-release version as described here: https://github.com/FooBarWidget/passenger/pull/71#issuecomment-14714397

Comment: Just used this to install a ruby 2.0 rails 4.0 install on an AWS EC2 instance. Worked like a charm. I did have to make sure the ruby racer was installed otherwise it complained about missing a javascript runtime when trying to rails s, but arguably outside the scope of this answer

Comment: 'rvm pkg' is deprecated, by the way. At least that's the message I get when I get to the step to install openssl. As of the time I'm replying here, the current stable version of Ruby is also no longer 2.0.0 but 2.1.0.

Comment: You should also run 'rvm --default use 2.1.0' when finished. After installing 2.1.0 according to these instructions, my default ruby was still the old 1.8.7 that came pre-installed with my EC2 instance.

Comment: I created an instance today with amazon/2013.09/x86_64 and Ruby 2.1.1 installed without a hitch, i.e. I didn't have to install rvm's openssl package, just ``sudo yum update``, ``yum groupinstall "Development Tools”`` and ``\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`` and ``rvm install ruby-2.1.1``

Comment: No dice for me. When I got to the step "rvm reinstall 2.0.0...." I got this: 
Error running '__rvm_make -j1',....
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
make: *** [parse.o] Error 4.....

And I'm afraid that's as detailed as it gets.

Comment: As this answer ages, can someone suggest an edit that would ensure installation of the latest versions of Ruby and RoR?

Answer (score 17):

Here is a variant with rbenv.

SSH into your brand new instance:

```
   __|  __|_  )
   _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
  ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2012.09-release-notes/
There are 16 security update(s) out of 57 total update(s) available
Run "sudo yum update" to apply all updates.
Amazon Linux version 2013.03 is available.
[jimjh ~]$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]
```

Impersonate the root and apply server updates:

```
$> sudo su -
$> yum update
```

Install couple of packages:

```
$> yum install git pcre pcre-devel
```

Clone [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv):

```bash
$> git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git /usr/local/rbenv
```

Create the following file:

```
# /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Install [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build):

```
$> . /etc/profile
$> git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git /usr/local/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

Install ruby:

```
$> rbenv install 2.0.0-p195  # wait ...
$> rbenv global 2.0.0-p195
$> rbenv rehash
```

Update rubygems and install passenger:

```
$> gem update --system
$> gem install bundler     
$> gem install passenger
```

Install nginx through passenger:

```
$> passenger start
```

At the time of writing, the latest version of passenger is 4.0.0, which works with ruby 2.0.0.

**Elastic Beanstalk**
If you are using Elastic Beanstalk, stop passenger

```
$> sudo service passenger stop
```

Initialize rbenv by adding the following to `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars.d/appenv`

```
. /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
```

Start passenger

```
$> sudo service passenger start
```

Comment: You might need to install openssl-devel as well. `yum install openssl-devel`

Comment: After updating ruby throught rbenv, when I deploy the app with elastic beanstalk nothing happens. Anyone knows what can be going on?

Comment: I had to add this command-  "yum install gcc" - no c compiler in instructions above (or did I miss it?)