# Using rbenv doesn't work with sudo?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

Any commands that use `sudo` don't seem to work with RBenv.

I'm trying to install ActiveRecord and it says I don't have write permission, so when I try this:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory.
```

It says:

```
sudo: gem: command not found
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Looks like you've installed rbenv at `/usr/local/rbenv` instead of `~/.rbenv`. You'll have better luck with permissions if you install in a user's home directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The idea behind tools like rbenv and RVM is that you don't need to use `sudo`, because your *entire* Ruby environment exists inside your own workspace as a sandbox.

RVM allows multi-user configurations though it was originally designed for single users.

As far as I've ever seen or read, rbenv is single-user only. At no time should you need to use `sudo` to manipulate or change your Ruby environment when using rbenv. If you do, something is wrong. If you try to use `sudo`, you'll screw things up. You might not find out immediately but eventually something will pop up and you'll need to change the ownership of the files back to you.

On Linux and Mac OS you can do that pretty easily using:

```
sudo chown -R <your_user_name>:<your_group> ~/.rbenv
```

You have to run that as `sudo` because only the super-user can change ownership of files owned by root. `sudo` escalates your privileges to allow you to change those things.

Comment: There are times you will want to use sudo even if you have a sandbox. For instance, you want to use chef-solo installed as a gem by a Ruby managed by rbenv. In RVM you can use rvmsudo for doing things like that. I'm looking for an alternative for rbenv.

Comment: People use `sudo rvm ...` and `sudo rbenv ...`, which is not the same as `rvmsudo`. The first two cause all sorts of problems. That's what this question and answer was about.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is kind of old now, but this may help people in future:

> rbenv-sudo is a plugin for rbenv that allows you to run rbenv-provided Rubies and Gems from within a sudo session.

https://github.com/dcarley/rbenv-sudo

Comment: better idea: `sudo env PATH=$PATH bundle exec ...`

Answer (score 0):

My answer in "[Installing Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0.0beta on AWS EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535140/installing-ruby-2-0-and-rails-4-0-0beta-on-aws-ec2/16990152#16990152)" might be useful to you.

In short, the root user needs to have `rbenv` loaded in its environment for you to use the gems installed by rbenv. This can be done by adding the following

```
# /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

This should be sufficient for `sudo` to work. If you are writing a shell script, you might need to use

```
. /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
```

before using executables from other gems.

Comment: A problem with this approach is that when "rbenv init -" is evaluated as the root user, it will modify the rbenv/shims directory and by doing so change the ownership to root. Then when the same command is run by a user it will fail with a permission denied error. Similar problems occur when installing ruby versions and/or gems as root.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is a little bit late but I have simple solution for this issue. Use symbolic links to be able use binstubs and other Ruby stuff.

```
ln -s ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv /usr/local/bin/rbenv
ln -s ~/.rbenv/shims/* /usr/local/bin
```

I hope that helps to other users who is having the same issue.

Comment: rbenv manages creating links to executables created by gems. See https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-rehash. If rbenv is set up correctly it's not necessary to put links in /usr/local at all as the PATH should point to the right place.