# different ruby version in sudo

Tags: ruby, macos, sudo, rbenv

I am using `OSX 10.10.3` and use `rbenv` to use ruby.

when I run `ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

when I run `sudo ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
```

the versions in rbenv(both sudo and regular run):

```
  system
* 2.2.1 (set by /Users/shalev/.rbenv/version)
```

how can I change the ruby version in sudo and why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try to set the rbenv version as global? `rbenv global 2.2.1`

Comment: yes still gets `ruby 2.0.0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using rbenv doesn't work with sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071242/using-rbenv-doesnt-work-with-sudo)