# LoadError when requiring Sinatra Gem in app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I'm following the tutorial http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex50.html, which provides:

> create the most basic Sinatra application possible. Put the following code into `bin/app.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :port, 8080
set :static, true
set :public_folder, "static"
set :views, "views"

get '/' do
    return 'Hello world'
end
```

I installed gem and Sinatra without a problem. I also copied the `app.rb` from the tutorial into my local `bin/app.rb` file.

I ran it with: `ruby bin/app.rb`

The terminal outputs:

```
/home/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require': cannot load such file -- sinatra (LoadError)
    from /home/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
    from bin/app.rb:1:in `<main>
```

When I run `rake test` it passes the test. What's the problem?

Comment: Please take a moment to format your question correctly. Code blocks should be indented four spaces, which you can do easily by clicking on the  `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Did you already run `bundle install`?

Comment: No I didn't. Thanks. I installed it and the problem persists. Any other idea?

Answer (score 5):

If you're following their directions you ran `sudo gem install sinatra`. Don't use `sudo` in your environment because you're using rbenv.

When you used `sudo`, you had the System Ruby install Sinatra, not your currently selected Ruby as set by rbenv.

Read rbenv's "[Installing Ruby gems](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-gems)" documentation.

To fix the problem simply run `gem install sinatra`, which will install Sinatra and its dependencies in your rbenv-configured Ruby.

That won't remove Sinatra from the System Ruby, but its existence there should be safe and benign.

"[Using rbenv doesn't work with sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19071242/128421)" will help too.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Tin Man.