# How to install rbenv, Ruby, gems and Rails as root user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed rbenv, Ruby, gems and Rails as the root user, so I cannot run Ruby as a normal user.

When I try using `bundle install`, it returns:

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
```

I tried to run it as a normal user, but rbenv, Ruby, gems and Rails are not working.

How can I make them available to normal users?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and followed "[Groom your app’s Ruby environment with rbenv.](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)" to install.

Comment: Did you uninstall the rbenv installation you did as root? Who did you try to install rbenv for the current user? did you encounter any issue? be more specific if you have an error as a normal non-root user.

Comment: @arieljuod I shifted to Windows and everything goes fine but when I try to use rails db:migrate, it stucks.

Comment: I haven't use windows for the last 5 years, I only know it doesn't work good for rails development but I can't help you there. Personally I would try to fix the linux rbenv installation (or try RVM instead of rbenv)

Comment: See "[Using rbenv doesn't work with sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19074129/128421)"

Answer (score 1):

[Uninstall rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), you may need to use `sudo` or to start a shell as `root` that means run the command `sudo su`. Then run `exit` to go back to normal user.

Then install rbenv again as normal user. Ubuntu 14.04 is no longer supported so if you can upgrade to 16.04 you may follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04) or if you have to use ubuntu 14.04 install following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04) (as normal user).